# Identifing the longest not mentioned item in a specific column in a google doc

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-docs

i am trying to find the longest not mentioned item in a column. 
I am creating a google doc about video uploads on a youtube channel. Specifically about several videos on Dota 2.
I got all the upload dates in my first column, and the hero in the second one. 
But now i would like to find the hero, which hasn't gotten a video in the longest time.
But i don't really see how to do this.
I will link the google doc so you can see what i mean.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uadKB4Psd310OwDdZyvSe7VViilTJGQT-V8Js3i402o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your explanation, you are looking to identify the 'hero' with the least recent date in your spreadsheet. To do this, I would suggest entering the following in cell I3 in your sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(B:B=G3,A:A,0)))
```

Then drag this down column I to find the most recent dates for each hero. Then, wherever you want to display the least recent hero, enter the following formula:

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(MIN(I:I),I:I,0),0)
```

This will show what you are looking for! Unfortunately if there are 2 heroes with the same most recent date it will only show the one which appears higher up your list in column G

Hope that helps!

Mike

Comment: Hey, this works great. 
But the =ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(B:B=G3,A:A,0))) returns numbers, which i don't really understand. 
The hero, that gets returned is correct tho, so thanks.

Comment: Hi seppdepp3, glad I was able to help. I think the reason it is showing numbers is down to the cell formatting, and it is showing the date in number format. To correct this, select the cells in column I then click on the small '123' dropdown in the ribbon, and select Date. This should make the numbers display in a date format.